# Run a macro on a different file (Multiple files)

Tags: excel

I have a template file where I plan to store the macro, this macro will be used to run on many files that will check the checkboxes of the file/s.

This is the current code:

[image]

Comment: Could you paste the code as text rather than as an image - really hard to copy images of code into Excel.

Comment: Also worth looking at this answer: [how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).  You're not using SELECT, but the principles apply to referencing a different workbook.

Comment: store the macro in your personal file. https://bettersolutions.com/excel/macros/personal-xlsb.htm